# Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, javascript, exceptions

The code below gives me the exceeds allowance or always failing  transaction error but when i check my contract on remix i can see that the transaction goes through, makes the correct state changes and works as expected. In The assignment `executionMetrics` becomes undefined. I've been sitting trying to figure out the problem for 4hrs and I'm completely stuck. Anyone knows what's going on?

```js
async function someAsyncFunc(){
  bookingPromiseArr = []
  let promise = instance.methods.bookTrip(tripKey).send({
    from: accounts[0],
    gasPrice: GAS_PRICE,
    value: 1,})
  bookingPromiseArr.push(promise)
  let executionMetrics = await executePromises(bookingPromiseArr, txStartTime)
}

async function executePromises(promisesArr, txStartTime) {
  await Promise.all(promisesArr)
    .then((receipts) => {
      let totalGasUsed = 0
      let txElapsedTime = Date.now() - txStartTime
      let lastBlock = receipts[receipts.length - 1].blockNumber
      receipts.forEach((receipt) => {
        totalGasUsed += receipt.gasUsed
        lastBlock =
          receipt.blockNumber > lastBlock ? receipt.blockNumber : lastBlock
      })
      // I've console logged here and seen that I've reached this point
      return {
        txElapsedTime: txElapsedTime,
        totalGasUsed: totalGasUsed,
        lastBlock: lastBlock,
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('multipleTX():', error)
      process.exit(1)
    })
}
```

The smart contract function invoked:

```js
function bookTrip(uint256 key) external payable requireTrip(key) nonBookedPassenger(key){
        Trip storage trip = trips[key];
        trip.passengers[msg.sender] = trip.price;
        trip.passengerCount++;
        emit LogNewTripPassenger(msg.sender, key, trip.price);
    }
```

Error log:

```
(node:23524) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: gas required exceeds allowance (8000029
) or always failing transaction
    at C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules\@truffle\hdw
allet-provider\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\subproviders\provider.js:18:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\exa
mensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:96:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\exame
nsarbete\tqdt33\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request-event-target.ts:44:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\t
qdt33\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:219:8)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbe
te\tqdt33\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:345:8)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqd
t33\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:311:39)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
(node:23524) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error origin
ated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23524) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In th
e future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a n
on-zero exit code.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'txElapsedTime' of undefined
    at multipleTx (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\client\cl-int
eraction\contractInteract.js:65:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at test (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\client\cl-interacti
on\profile1.js:26:5)
```

Comment: Your code does not make any sense with respect to your question. You can use `await` only inside an `async` function. The first line of code in your question does not abide to that rule. And since your question is specifically about this assignment becoming undefined, you need to explain exactly how you are doing things. This code will not even start running!

Comment: Oh i'm sorry these are just snippets of code i thought posting all of it would just be too messy. I am aware that await only works in async functions

Comment: Of course you shouldn't post all of it, only what's relevant to your question. But this specific handling IS very much relevant.

Comment: I updated my post. Hopefully the specific handling is more clear now

Comment: You are not calling function `someAsyncFunc` anywhere in your code! Even if you did, it is nor returning anything, not is it assigning any non-local variable. So what exactly is the purpose of this function, and how do you expect the local variable `executionMetrics` to have any meaning outside of it???

Comment: This doesn't seem like an Ethereum-related problem, but a pure Javascript problem (or more precisely, a basic programming concepts problem). A function doesn't get executed unless you call it explicitly. It won't return anything unless you add a `return` statement explicitly in every execution path within that function. A local variable has no meaning outside the function in which it is declared.

Comment: You're right this was infact just a javascript/basic programming error and I finally got it working the way i intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As goodvibration pointed out in his comments this wasn't a ethereum or web3 problem but a pure javascript/basic programming error. The big mistake in the code was returning in the `then()`-statement and assuming that it would be the return value for `executePromises()`. That wasn't the case and i have corrected it.